# JQuery set value for the json: path provided as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, updates

I have a string that carry the path of a nested json, where I need to update a value

```
var path = 'p_Data[0]["BusinessUnit"][0]["BusinessUnit"]'
```

if i evaluate this path I get value as 'Unit1'. I need to update the value 'Unit1' with 'Closed' and retrieve the original data ie, `p_Data`

I tried `eval(path = 'Closed')`, but didn't work.

How to do this?

Comment: did you use jsonpath???  It's a good plugin to manipulate json strings....

Comment: @maverickosama92: isn't there any other way to do this other than having another plugin?

Comment: FWIW, that's not a JSON string, that's just a string. And I assume you already parsed the JSON data and work with nested objects (so the problem does not have anything to do with JSON). Have a look at [Javascript: How to set object property given its string name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13719593/218196) for a start.

Comment: @FelixKling 'JSON string' was a careless mistake sry

Comment: I haven't worked much with nested JSON this is my first try with nested.

Comment: Issue is that I have arrays inside these nested json it can be like  var path = 'p_Data[0]["BusinessUnit"][1]["BusinessUnit"]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval(path + "='Closed'");
```

But have a look at this thread: [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).