# Find and update nested JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I need to find and update json object from nested json object. Consider the original json object.

```
  var originaldata=[
    {
    "sc_iden": "331",
    "sc_name": "Scene 1",
    "sc_type": "",
    "sc_status": "Draft",
    "sc_owner": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "sc_iden": "332",
            "Sc_name": "Scene1.1",
            "sc_type": "",
            "sc_status": "Draft",
            "sc_priority": "3",
            "sc_owner": "",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
},
{
    "sc_iden": "334",
    "sc_name": "Scene2",
    "sc_type": "",
    "sc_status": "Draft",
    "sc_priority": "2",
    "sc_owner": "",
    "children": []
}]
```

Find the below findUpdate record from originaldata(JSON) and update their values.

```
    var findUpdate =  {
            "sc_iden": "332",
            "Sc_name": "My Scene",
            "sc_type": "New Type",
            "sc_status": "Opened",
            "sc_priority": "5",
            "sc_owner": "Admin",
            "children": []
        }
```

Based on sc_iden ="332" search the originaldata and update new values(findUpdate) by using jquery or angularjs.

Comment: I tired with following link but here they update single value only but i need to update all the records. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993296/find-and-update-in-nested-json-object-without-changing-the-same-key-pair-value-i

Comment: Try Linq.js. You'll love it!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wa3eQuOd0eGSbzLawlo3?p=preview) .

```
var update = function(jsonArray, updatedJson) {

  if (jsonArray.length !== 0) {
    jsonArray.forEach(function(obj) {
      if (obj.sc_iden === updatedJson.sc_iden) {
        obj.sc_name = updatedJson.sc_name;
        //....update
      } else {
        //try to update children
        update(obj.children, updatedJson);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

It will modify the original data, so keep a copy if you still need that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the console output (in the example only `Sc_name` is changed):

```js
var originaldata=[
    {
    "sc_iden": "331",
    "sc_name": "Scene 1",
    "sc_type": "",
    "sc_status": "Draft",
    "sc_owner": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "sc_iden": "332",
            "Sc_name": "Scene1.1",
            "sc_type": "",
            "sc_status": "Draft",
            "sc_priority": "3",
            "sc_owner": "",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
},
{
    "sc_iden": "334",
    "sc_name": "Scene2",
    "sc_type": "",
    "sc_status": "Draft",
    "sc_priority": "2",
    "sc_owner": "",
    "children": []
}];

var findUpdate =  {
            "sc_iden": "332",
            "Sc_name": "My Scene",
            "sc_type": "New Type",
            "sc_status": "Opened",
            "sc_priority": "5",
            "sc_owner": "Admin",
            "children": []
        }

for (i in originaldata) {
  var obj = originaldata[i];
  if (obj['sc_iden'] == '332') {
    obj['Sc_name'] = findUpdate['Sc_name'];
    //...
  } else {
    for (m in obj['children']) {
      var k = obj['children'][m];
      if (k['sc_iden'] == '332') {
        k['Sc_name'] = findUpdate['Sc_name'];
        //...
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(originaldata);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```